# Create User Account locally on all workstations?

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy

The company no longer required the need of Windows Servers 2012.

Is it possible to deploy via GPO to create User account without password (standard user) locally on all workstations?

I like to do this before I remove the domains back to Workgroup on all workstation. It would save me a lot of time creating user account locally on each PC.

Answer (score 1):

It's no longer possible to create local user accounts with Group Policy Preferences, but you can create them with the ***net user*** command.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2962486/ms14-025-vulnerability-in-group-policy-preferences-could-allow-elevati

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/SecurityBulletins/2014/ms14-025

Comment: I like it. But it is probably good to point out that creating a local user account without a password is typically not possible because the domain will require a strong password. So group policy will need to be changed to allow weak passwords. The user accounts created by `net user` also have a password that expires after 30 days, so an additional step is necessary to turn off the password expiry, usually involving a wmic command.

Comment: AFAIK, the net user command requires setting a password when creating a user, so I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: You can create a user with a blank password using net user, if policy allows. The problem is the “password” expires after 30 days, confusing the user after asking them to enter the current password and forcing them to set a new password. They don’t realize they have to just push enter, resulting in a “I’m locked out of my computer,” phone call. They’ll continue to be prompted every 30 days unless the password expiry is disabled on the account.

Comment: Sorry, I think the time is 90 days. See here for a hint of the problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/434717/how-to-create-a-never-expiring-password-user-via-net-user-through-bat-file

Comment: And here is a discussion about setting a blank password with net user: https://superuser.com/questions/122764/remove-a-users-password-using-net-command